# EasyCanvas iPad pro and Blender?

Tags: interface

Hey I just installed an Astropad Windows Alternative EasyCanvas, it works fine but blender doesn't seem to detect pressure from Apple pencil. Is there any way to fix it, my iPad shows as a generic HID Compilant pen?

Answer (score 0):

in preferences
Click ‘Input’ - Change the ‘Tablet API’ to ‘Windows Ink’.
http://www.easynlight.com/en/supporteasycanvas/?faq=75
worked for me :)